# how do you use Grid layout in panels in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, grid-layout

Im trying to create a JFrame with two panels. the top panel will contain a text field and the bottom panel will contain a grid of buttons. Ive used gridLayout to to arrange the buttons and added them into a panel and added the panel to the JFrame but according to the editor the value of panel is NULL. The same is true of the second panel. Could someone help direct me to the problem?

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class frameClass extends JFrame{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JFrame frame;

private JPanel panel;
private JPanel panel2;

private JButton button0;
private JButton button1;
private JButton button2;
private JButton button3;

public frameClass() {
    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4,4,5,5));            

    panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

    Font font1 = new Font("SanSerif",Font.BOLD, 16);

    button0 = new JButton("0");
    button0.setFont(font1);
    button0.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button0.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.add(button0);

    button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.setFont(font1);
    button1.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.add(button1);

    button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.setFont(font1);
    button2.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    button2.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.add(button2);

    button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.setFont(font1);
    button3.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    panel.add(button3);

            frame.add(panel);
            panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    panel2.add(new JTextField(21), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new calculator();       
}
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: You appear to be trying to use a `panel1` variable that was never declared, and you've declared a `panel2` variable that is never used. Does this code even compile?

Comment: Quoted from an answer by [Alexander Lin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2708998/alexander-lin) *Are you sure this code is current? You have `panel1.add(new JTextField(21), BorderLayout.CENTER);`, but it does seem like you declared `private JPanel panel2;`. Is this in your application?*

Comment: The code in the latest edit still does not *compile* cleanly.   So therefore *cannot* be an SSCCE of a *run-time* problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "core" problem isn't that the panel's are null, but `frame` is null...

```
// You extend from JFrame, which isn't highly recommended
// but you seem to ignore...
public class FrameClass extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    // Instance variable of frame, but it's never initialised...
    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel panel2;

    //...

    public FrameClass() {
        // Create panel...
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));
        panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        //...

        // Add it to frame, but frame is null...
        frame.add(panel);

        //...
    }
```

Instead, try removing the `extends JFrame` and instantiate an instance of `JFrame`

```
public class FrameClass {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JFrame frame;

    private JPanel panel;
    private JPanel panel2;

    //...

    public FrameClass() {
        panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(4, 4, 5, 5));

        //...

        frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.add(panel);
        panel2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel2.add(new JTextField(21), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.add(panel2);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I see now that I forgot to instantiate the frame before I filled it. In addition instead of placing both panels in the frame I had to place the panel containing the JTextField inside the panel with the buttons and set the border layout to north.